# my set request header is not working it is not setting parameters to my url on running the function

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

I m trying to make a post request to the server by clicking a button

FYI this code is in HTML file

```
      <button  onclick="vf()"  >click</button>  
      
      <!---script---->
      <script>
        function vf(){
      var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ///aServe= anyserver
      var url = 'aServer';
      var myName = 'name=me';
      http.open('POST', url, true);

      ///setting header
      http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
              alert(http.responseURL);
             }
           }

      http.send(myName);

        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Consider using `fetch` over `XMLHttpRequest`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API --- Also what's not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I m not getting my parameter with my URL

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the example code posted. The issue may lie elsewhere. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

Comment: if I try to run this function vf() my post request should have a URL like "aServer?name=me" but in this case it is only making a request as    "aServer/"

Comment: No that's a GET request. You're making a POST request.

Comment: i don't think in this case, it does matter if it is POST or GET. it should at least attach my string to the URL. you know that i m using setrequestheader() module

Comment: I don't know what that last part means. --- POST doesn't attach anything to the URL string. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp